# How do I turn a RGB picture in a B/W portrait in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I used to be a big fan of a band called Maximum The Hormone and i decided to check out one of their songs, which soon led me to revisit their site. On there I roamed and visited their band page. I noticed they had an awesome picture of themselves in a black and white tent, which can be seen [here](http://www.maximumthehormone.jp/band.html). I was wondering if anyone knew how to perform this task in Photoshop? or if you knew a site which showed a tutorial for this. I currently run CC edition and I am pretty familiar with some of the basic layer adjustments. I just want to make cool photos for Facebook and stuff like that. I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I am more of a fan of the Exposure or Shadows/Highlight options as I feel they give finer control to the levels of the darks and lights along with the gamma correction needed to get really sharp curves to mimic the OP image mentioned...

- Take your photo:

[image]

- De-saturate it by switching the mode to `Grayscale`:

[image]

- Adjust the image using `Exposure` or `Shadows/Highlights`:

[image]

- Adjust the `Shadows/Highlights` to your liking (remember to tick the `Show More Options` box):

[image]

- Or adjust the `Exposure` as you need:

[image]

Comment: That is a great example. I tried it the method comes out pretty close. Thankyou, and thanks to everyone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

To make it black and white go to Image => Adjustment => Disaturate
To make it look like a poster do Image => Adjustment => Posterize

you can play with levels to make it a bit more interesting

Answer (score 0):

Click on the adjustment layer button (the little circular icon at the bottom of your layers palette)

Select either `Black & White` or `Hue/Saturation`. Black and White is a one-click option. With Hue/Saturation, you can dial down the sliders and play with the levels.